# operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shape

Tags: python, numpy

I keep getting this error message: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (1000,)  and requested shape (1000,1)

I do understand the concept behind it but I do not see where, and how to fix the code, which part of my code is causing that error?

```
# We must always import the relevant libraries for our problem at hand. NumPy is a must for this example.
import numpy as np

# matplotlib and mpl_toolkits are not necessary. We employ them for the sole purpose of visualizing the results.  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# First, we should declare a variable containing the size of the training set we want to generate.
observations = 1000

# We will work with two variables as inputs. You can think about them as x1 and x2 in our previous examples.
# We have picked x and z, since it is easier to differentiate them.
# We generate them randomly, drawing from an uniform distribution. There are 3 arguments of this method (low, high, size).
# The size of xs and zs is observations x 1. In this case: 1000 x 1.
xs = np.random.uniform(low=-10, high=10, size=(observations,1))
zs = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, (observations,1))

# Combine the two dimensions.сх of the input into one input matrix. 
# This is the X matrix from the linear model y = x*w + b.
# column_stack is a Numpy method, which combines two matrices (vectors) into one.
inputs = np.column_stack((xs,zs))

# Check if the dimensions of the inputs are the same as the ones we defined in the linear model lectures. 
# They should be n x k, where n is the number of observations, and k is the number of variables, so 1000 x 2.
print (inputs.shape)

# We add a random small noise to the function i.e. f(x,z) = 2x - 3z + 5 + <small noise>
noise = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (observations,1))

# Produce the targets according to our f(x,z) = 2x - 3z + 5 + noise definition.
# In this way, we are basically saying: the weights should be 2 and -3, while the bias is 5.
targets = 2*xs - 3*zs + 5 + noise

# Check the shape of the targets just in case.
print (targets.shape)

# In order to use the 3D plot, the objects should have a certain shape, so we reshape the targets.
# The proper method to use is reshape and takes as arguments the dimensions in which we want to fit the object.
targets = targets.reshape(observations,)

# Plotting according to the conventional matplotlib.pyplot syntax

# Declare the figure
fig = plt.figure()

# A method allowing us to create the 3D plot
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Choose the axes.
ax.plot(xs, zs, targets)

# Set labels
ax.set_xlabel('xs')
ax.set_ylabel('zs')
ax.set_zlabel('Targets')

# You can fiddle with the azim parameter to plot the data from different angles. Just change the value of azim=100
# to azim = 0 ; azim = 200, or whatever. Check and see what happens.
ax.view_init(azim=100)

# So far we were just describing the plot. This method actually shows the plot. 
plt.show()

# We reshape the targets back to the shape that they were in before plotting.
# This reshaping is a side-effect of the 3D plot. Sorry for that.
targets = targets.reshape(observations,1)
```

Comment: when you debug it line by line, doesn't it break in the exact line that causes the error?

Comment: I have no idea where the error occurs, since you only showed an piece of the error message.  With `broadcasting`, leading dimensions can be added automatically, trailing ones have to be explicit.  In other words it can make a (1000,) to (1,1000), but not (1000,1).

Comment: Squeeze the singleton dimension: `ax.plot(xs[:, 0], zs[:, 0], targets)`

Comment: Thanks for asking. Answered my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicate your situation in my system and it works fine. Your code is fine, no bug at all.

I think there is an issue with the library version. You can try this version it perfectly works on my system.

```
Numpy version: 1.21.6
Matplotlib version: 3.2.2
```

I run your code on this version and it works fine you can try it once.

Answer (score 0):

The way i solved it on my current library:

is that I changed
'''
ax.plot(xs, zs, targets)
'''

to this
'''
ax.plot(xs.reshape(observations,), zs, targets)
'''

and that worked well